# save images in hdf5 files

Tags: python, image, numpy, h5py

I'm using python 3.4.2 and I was wondering to know if there is any way to save images to hdf5 files without change the attributes of dataset.
I mean, I want to use the HDFViewer to see this images later.

What I'm doing...
I'm using the h5py package to save images as numpy array in different datasets. Then a need to change the datasets attributes.

My final result is already what I have imagined. But I'm not really happy.

If there is another way, please share here...

Comment: It isn't clear why you are unhappy.  "CLASS" and "IMAGE_VERSION" attributes are required by the HDF5 Image specification.  `h5py` lets you assign the values before or after you set up the attributes --- Why can't you can set up the data set with its attributes and then fill in the values afterwards?  Perhaps a code example would make this more clear.

Comment: Check out this possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724553/add-raster-image-to-hdf5-file-using-h5py