# Add raster image to HDF5 file using h5py

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, raster, h5py

I apologize if this is sort of a newbie question, but I am fairly new to Python and HDF5.  I am using h5py, numpy, and Python 2.7.  I have data from various files that need to be imported into one HDF5 file.  The data from each file is to be stored in a different group.  Each of these groups needs to contain 1) the raw data from the file as an m x n matrix and 2) an image raster generated from normalized raw data.

I am able to accomplish part 1, and am able to normalize the data, but I am not able to write this normalized data to a raster image because I don't know how to add a raster image to a group.  It seems like there should be an easy, straightforward way to do this, but I have read the documentation and haven't found one.  How would one do this in h5py, and if it can't be done using h5py, what should I use to accomplish this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is the raster image a `numpy` array?  Is the data an array as well?  Reread the `h5py` documentation.  I believe the `numpy` array is the basic unit of data that you can add with that package.

Comment: http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html - `create_dataset` is the basic mechanism for adding numpy arrays to a group.

Comment: I can add an array of data as an m x n matrix, but how do I add it such that it will display as an image; such as the ones in here:  [link](http://hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/h5image.html) using h5py?

Comment: It's possible that `h5py` has not included this image API in its port.  You might have to ask the developers: https://github.com/h5py/h5py

Comment: why not save the array as it is and then have separate `matplotlib` code that plots it as an image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing special about images in HDF5. The [link](http://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/h5image.html) you provided is for the high level library bindings. You can just as easily use the [specifications](http://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/ADGuide/ImageSpec.html) of images in HDF5, which are just attributes.

Here is a **very** quick and dirty example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import h5py

# Define a color palette
pal =  np.array([[0,     0, 168],
                 [0,     0, 252],
                 [0,   168, 252],
                 [84,  252, 252],
                 [168, 252, 168],
                 [0,   252, 168],
                 [252, 252,  84],
                 [252, 168,   0],
                 [252,   0,   0]],
                 dtype=np.uint8
               )

# Generate some data/image
x = np.linspace(0,pal.shape[0]-1)
data,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)

# Create the HDF5 file
f = h5py.File('test.h5', 'w')

# Create the image and palette dataspaces
dset = f.create_dataset('img', data=data)
pset = f.create_dataset('palette', data=pal)

# Set the image attributes
dset.attrs['CLASS'] = 'IMAGE'
dset.attrs['IMAGE_VERSION'] = '1.2'
dset.attrs['IMAGE_SUBCLASS'] =  'IMAGE_INDEXED'
dset.attrs['IMAGE_MINMAXRANGE'] = np.array([0,255], dtype=np.uint8)
dset.attrs['PALETTE'] = pset.ref

# Set the palette attributes
pset.attrs['CLASS'] = 'PALETTE'
pset.attrs['PAL_VERSION'] = '1.2'
pset.attrs['PAL_COLORMODEL'] = 'RGB'
pset.attrs['PAL_TYPE'] = 'STANDARD8'

# Close the file
f.close()
```

---

Run the example and then look at the image in HDFView:

[image: Image within HDF5 file]

Note that you have to open the image data with "Open As" in order to see it as an image, as the table view is the default.

Comment: Exactly this.  No idea how I missed this earlier when looking through docs.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @MojoJojo I don't use Matlab, however there is an answer on the [Matlab Answers website](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93316-is-it-possible-to-open-hdf5-h5-images-in-matlab). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! This is an excellent answer. For completeness, here are the attributes I have used for a single channel, grayscale image: `{
    'CLASS': 'IMAGE',
    'IMAGE_VERSION': '1.2',
    'IMAGE_SUBCLASS': 'IMAGE_GRAYSCALE',
    'IMAGE_MINMAXRANGE': np.array([0, 255], dtype=np.uint8),
    'IMAGE_WHITE_IS_ZERO': 0,
}`

Comment: The links posted are deprecated. They should be updated to https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/h5image.html and
 https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/ADGuide/ImageSpec.html